# LyX: Question mark [?] instead of reference number after installing new .bst file

Tags: bibtex, lyx, citing, mactex

Hello I'm new in using LyX 2.0.6 with MacTex, and I'd try to import a citation style (file named `plos2009.bst` from http://www.ploscompbiol.org/static/latexGuidelines) into the BibTex style folder.

I added the `.bst` file with reference to the way suggested: http://www.flukylogs.blogspot.com/2009/09/install-style-files-in-lyx.html (I have tried both methods of directly dragging the .bst file to the folder and using the terminal).

After reconfigure LyX the new citation style of "plos2009" appeared under the "style" scroll bar in "insert -> citation". However the PDF document generated only contain [?] instead of the reference number. Instead there is no such problem if the `.bst` file was moved to the desktop and linking it by pressing "Browse" in "insert -> citation".

There was no problem in using the pre-exist citation style inside LyX like Vancouver style. I would like to know the reason.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Have you tried running it a couple of times?

Answer (score 2):

BibTeX is probably exiting with errors but LyX is not telling you because of this bug:
http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/2757

To see what the error is, go to

> Document > LaTeX Log

Under `Log Type`, change it from `LaTeX` to `BibTeX`. Then use the `Next Error` and `Next Warning` buttons to navigate.