# LyX Problem when referencing. Just question mark [?]

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, lyx, citing

I am very new to LyX (no LaTeX background whatsoever) and cannot manage to properly insert citations. The problem is, within LyX the citation seems ok  `[Sayer`], but when I render the PDF, I only get `[?]`.

I have found similar problems, but with that information I can't make it work.

[LyX: Question mark [?] instead of reference number after installing new .bst file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114640/lyx-question-mark-instead-of-reference-number-after-installing-new-bst-fil)
[Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-instead-of-citation-number)

As I understand, the two possible problems are unicode related, and some communication problem between BibTeX and LyX.

I can insert citations from LyX, which means that at least it knows where the DB is, and apparently "understands" it. It's just a test, but this is what the DB contains (no strange unicode)

```
@book{Sayer,
  author={Natalie J. Sayer},
  title={Lean for Dummies}
}
```

And... when I check the log `Document > LaTeX Log`, I get the following Warning:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation `Sayer' on page 1 undefined on input line 124.
```

Which yes, makes all the sense of the world, but I don't know what to do next.

**EDIT**

I have realized that I get different mistakes if I try to create the PDF from the "parent" file or from the "child" (i.e.: lyx document within lyx doc). From the child doc, the PDF is created with that `[?]`, but from the parent doc, it does not even compile. Apparently there is one mistake per reference I have introduced in the children docs:

```
 ...Mass-Production-vs.-Lean-Enterprise}\citep
                                                  {Sayer}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Maybe this helps.

Comment: What is the citation style when you right-click the citation and choose settings...? Also try changing Document->Settings...->Bibliography to use Natbib instead.

Comment: It shows `[#ID]`. I tried with Natbib and just shows the same error in different formats like `(?)`.

Comment: Try using Natbib instead and see if the output is OK.

Comment: Now the error report says: `Package natbib Warning: Citation 'Sayer' on page 1 undefined on input line 125.`

Comment: This isn't an error, is a warning. What the output looks like?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Feel free to visit our [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: The output (you mean the PDF, right?) looks the same: instead of any text or number, just a `?`

Comment: I uploaded the question with some extra info. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `\citep` is defined by `natbib`, so the error in the master document is probably caused by `natbib` not being used.